# How to use react as a component library rather than application

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-mvc-4, webpack

I'm trying to learn react and also introduce it in already existing project. Thus I want to use react in a few places where it makes sense, instead of using it everywhere.

The problem is the entry-point concept that I can't wrap my head around. I'd prefer to have:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <MyComponent/>,
    document.getElementById("componentExample")
);
```

inside my `cshtml` near `<div id='componentExample'></div>` rather than in a separate `jsx`. I understand that I can't use `jsx` syntax in `cshtml`, but if I write

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/dist/bundle.js")"></script>
<script>
    ReactDOM.render(
        React.createElement(MyComponent, {}, null), document.getElementById("componentExample")
    );
</script>
```

This doesn't really work because `MyComponent` is undefined. It is included in my `bundle.js` (I had to add it as entry point), but it is inside the scope of some `webpack` stuff and is not exposed.

What is the proper way of doing this?

My goal is to write some components for my app where it is more suitable and use it here and there, without completely going into react-based architecture.

My setup is `webpack` + `babel polyfill` + `typescript` + `react` and this is in `ASP.NET MVC`.

My `webpack.config.js` is:

```
var config = {
    entry: ['babel-polyfill', "./SiteScripts/React/index.tsx", "./SiteScripts/React/Components/MyComponent.tsx"],
    output: {
        filename: "./Scripts/dist/bundle.js",
    },

    // Enable sourcemaps for debugging webpack's output.
    devtool: "source-map",

    resolve: {
        // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
        extensions: [".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
            {
                enforce: 'pre',
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: "source-map-loader"
            },

            // All files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'ts-loader'.
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/, loaders: ['babel-loader', "ts-loader"], exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins : []
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    config.devtool = "cheap-module-source-map";
}


module.exports = config;
```

Also this is somewhat related to the question (as question about architecture): I'd like to make my `bundle.js` smaller - it is 30k lines now. It is probably because I'm trying to use `react` in a wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem. I had a few mistakes (and didn't completely understand the whole theory behind webpack) and the answer is definetely beyound the code I gave in the question - so I do not have any answers.

First I had to make by bundle a library, in order to export stuff defined in it (`webpack.config.js`):

```
 entry: ['babel-polyfill', "./SiteScripts/React/index.tsx"],
 output: {
        filename: "./Scripts/dist/bundle.js",
        libraryTarget: "var",
        library: "WebPack"
    },
```

This will make types/variables defined in `index.tsx` (I think only last file from entry list is taken) and that are `exported` - available via `WebPack.<name>`

I needed to export my component. I've done it like this - but there are probably better ways (`index.tsx`):

```
import { MyComponent} from "./Components/mycomponent";
export var myComponent = MyComponent;
```

I also needed to ensure all my subcomponents are modules. This means using `import` everywhere, and adding a keyword `export` to all element, props and states.

After that I was able to render my component from:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/dist/bundle.js")"></script>
<script>
    ReactDOM.render(
        React.createElement(WebPack.myComponent,
            {
                PropA = 2, PropB = "3"
            }, null),
        document.getElementById("componentExample")
    );
</script>
```

One more thing to watch for if I am doing this is that the line `<script src="@...` does not happen more than once in my result html (this is very likely as I am using many components embedded in a single page). I use this javascript function to ensure I load `bundle.js` only once:

```
function loadJsOnce(url, whenFinish) {
    if (!window.loadedScripts) {
        window.loadedScripts = {};
    }

    if (!window.loadedScripts[url]) {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        //script.async = true; // remove this if you don't want the script to be async
        script.src = url;
        script.onload = function() {
            whenFinish();
        }
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

        window.loadedScripts[url] = true;
    } else {
        whenFinish();
    }
}
```

In `url` I specify the path to `bundle.js` and in `whenFinish` function I put a function that calls `ReactDOM.render(...` stuff